# Laravel 5.5 blocking markdown textareas from being edited

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.5

I have included SimpleMDE into my Laravel 5.5 project (https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor).

```
npm install simplemde --save
```

In my bootstrap.js file I have the following:

```
window.markdown = require('simplemde');
var simplemde = new window.markdown();
```

This works as expected it binds the SimpleMDE to the first textarea on the page but I can't edit the textarea it's not selectable.

If I make the script error in some way like throw and error right after simplemde is instantiated it works perfectly:

```
window.markdown = require('simplemde');
var simplemde = new window.markdown();
throw 'fail';
```

So my guess is Laravel is doing something after this which is blocking the simplemde textarea from working correctly but I don't have enough knowledge of the Laravel frontend build tools to work out what's blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem and i did wrap the js around jquery document ready and it works for me.

old code:

```
<script>
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: document.getElementById('content') });
</script>
```

Working Code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: document.getElementById('content') });
    });
</script>
```